# How can I add discount to a product based on javascript variable value in shopify?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

In Shopify, I want add the discount to product based on js variable. This discount should be considered in checkout? Can I achieve that??

Comment: Would you mind being a bit more specific by providing examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to alter the price of a [line item](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/line_item) in a cart. You can only update the [product variant's price](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant#update).

See this similar question: [Shopify API CARTS - Changing line_item line_price for price Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752654/shopify-api-carts-changing-line-item-line-price-for-price-override)

Is it possible to use Shopify's built in [Discounts](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-store/discounts) in your situation?